# Laravel database result to javascript fullcalendar color change

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get results from the database put them in an array, get them via javascript and check if a value is set.

**CalendarController.php**

```
 public function tasks($id)
{
     $tasks = task::Findtasks()->select('tasks.*', 'tasks_times.*', 'tasks.name as title')
                               ->where('project_id', '=', $id)
                               ->join('tasks_times', 'tasks.id', '=', 'tasks_times.task_id')
                               ->get();

 return view('testcalendar', compact('tasks'));
}
```

as you can see i'm giving tasks to the view..

Now i have this piece of javascript script in a script tag on the "testcalendar" view.

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
        var dataHoje = new Date();
        var completed = <?php echo json_encode($tasks); ?>;
        var tasks = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($tasks); ?>')
        for (var i = 0; i < completed.length; i++) {
    if (completed[i]['completed'] == 3) {
     //event.color = "Groenoe"; 
     element.css('background-color', '#0eb505');
} else if (event.start < dataHoje && event.end < dataHoje) {
    //event.color = "Rood"; 
    element.css('background-color', '#fc0000');
} else if (event.start > dataHoje && event.end > dataHoje) {
    //event.color = "Blauw"; 
    element.css('background-color', '#27bec6');
}       
    }

},
```

so when "completed" = 3 i want the background-color to turn green. (Yes completed is a column in the database) if it's not 3 then it's need to be a diffrent color ofcourse.

Thank you x

Comment: So what is the issue with the above code?

Comment: The problem is that the console.log(tasks) shows tasks like 10 times instead of once which made the code not work. here is an example https://gyazo.com/4aefdf3788a9a5cddf5d4f38e40d89de

Comment: This is because the code is resides in `for (var i = 0; i < completed.length; i++) ` loop

Comment: yes that's correct becuase i have to check the indexes of the array, correct?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz ?

Comment: I am not able to get you

Comment: I don't know how i can explain it better but thanks anyway!

Comment: Let me know your skpe ID?

Comment: Lets come over skype